# Selenium preceding returns a pointer/address and full xpath return a different pointer/address to what I believe should be the same object

Tags: selenium, xpath

**Relative Xpath**

```
WebElement precedingClass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'pictures')]/preceding::div[contains (@class 'monkey picture') ]"));
```

**Absolute Xpath**

```
WebElment fullXpathAddress = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[20]/div[1]");
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="pictures">
 <a ref ....>
 <a ref ....>
 <h1>x's pictures</h1>
</div>
<div class="animals">
   <div class="monkey picture" title="happy monkey"></div>
   .
   .
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried something simple like a CSS selector, `div.monkey.picture` or `div[title='happy monkey']`?

Answer (score 1):

**Preceding:** Select all nodes that come before the current node.

And you want to select node that is after the current node.
Maybe you can use following as below :

```
"//div[contains(@class, 'pictures')]/following::div[@class='animals']/div[@class='monkey picture']"
```

please refer this [link](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html#14) to learn more about Xpaths

Please optimize the above Xpath based on your whole DOM structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your Xpath seems wrong

Try below Xpath:

```
//div[@class='pictures']/following-sibling::a//div[@class='monkey picture']
```

So the code will be like:

```
WebElment element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='pictures']/following-sibling::a//div[@class='monkey picture']");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use preceding::div[x] since I was able to determine index of div "monkey picture" in the list of animals and from the start of animals, the number of divs preceding to "pictures was a fixed value.